# Does the fullness of a pressure cooker effect it's performance?

Tags: pressure-cooker

We make stock in our pressure cooker and it ends up being quite full. Will this affect the cooking in some way? Will a pressure cooker that is only 1/3 full cook things differently than if it was 2/3s full? Does it depend on what is being cooked? Naturally it will take longer to come up to pressure the more full it is, but besides that will anything else be different?

Comment: I suspect that this depends on the type of type of mechanism.  The ones that constantly jiggle releasing air I assume going to be more consistent if they have a larger volume of air to leak out.   Newer cookers will lock at a given pressure, so they’re not constantly losing air, so might not be affected.  (Unless they get gummed up, as mentioned below).  Also beware of things that swell as you cook them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No difference...however, the risk of overfilling is that something clogs one of the safety mechanisms.  My Kuhn Rikon stove top pressure cooker has a max fill line (which I do slightly exceed from time to time) at about the 2/3 mark.